# WPF bind TextBlock "text" in one user control to textbox in another UserControl Where both of them are hosted in a Frame inside mainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

**SUMMARY OF THE PROBLEM:**

I have main window which has a frame and a button, in the frame i'm going to show one user control at a time (i provided an image of my usercontrol).
in the first UserControl, i will write 4 player names (two for each team).
after i press the button and i go to next usercontrol i want to show the names of the players in textblock. I also want to bind IsChecked property of radio button in first UserControl to the second UserControl. (i have other buttons that show up in mainWindow depends on what usercontrol is in the Frame right Now)

**WHAT I TRIED:**

I tried binding the textbox property to the textblock in the second usercontrol but it doesnt show or i cant access it.

because i have the button in the mainWindow i tried saving the names in variable then pass it to next usercontrol but didnt work also.
Also tried alot of random online solution i found online but nothing worked.
**i need a way to expose the property of First UserControl to be used in the Second UserControl**

**MY CODE**

MainWindow xaml

```
<Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True" x:Name="myGrid" >
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush x:Name="myBackground" ImageSource="background1.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
       
        </Grid.Background>
    
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height=" auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height=" 20" />

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <Frame  x:Name="Main" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" >
        
       

    </Frame>


    <Button Style="{StaticResource StandardButton}" Visibility="Visible" x:Name="playersBtn" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row ="2"  Margin="100,40,100,40" FontSize="36"  Content="إبدأ" FontFamily="Ara Hamah Homs" Padding="50,0" Background="#FFFFE900" Click="playerInfoBtn" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="Black"   >
        
        
    </Button>
```

MainWindow c#

```
namespace Try3
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    SoundPlayer MP = new SoundPlayer();




    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MP.SoundLocation = "C:/Users/eadh2/Desktop/game tries/try3/try3/sound1.wav";
        MP.PlayLooping();

        
    }

    private void playerInfoBtn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Main.Content = new PlayersInfoPage();
        playersBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        startBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        icon.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        ImageBrush b = new ImageBrush();
        b.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/background flat.png"));
        myGrid.Background = b;

    }


    private void startBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Main.Content = new gamePage();
        startBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        gamePageBoarder.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        
    }

    private void startBtn_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
               startBtn.Background = Brushes.DarkGreen;

        }
    }
       }
```

First usercontrol xaml to enter player names ([Image of First UserControl to enter player names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uuGS.png))

```
<UserControl x:Class="Try3.PlayersInfoPage"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Try3"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="862.179" d:DesignWidth="1210.632" >



<Grid  SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
  
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width=" *" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="AUTO" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"  />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"  />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"  />
        <RowDefinition Height=" *" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 

    <TextBlock  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="بيانات الفريق الأحمر" FontSize="36" Margin="50,0,50,0" FontFamily="Ara Hamah Homs"  />
    <TextBox x:Name="redFirst" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,30,0,20" Padding="10" FontSize="36" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Text="اللاعب الأول" Foreground="#FF919191" GotMouseCapture="redFirst_GotMouseCapture" FontFamily="Ara Hamah Homs" />
    <TextBox x:Name="redSecond" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,30,0,110" Padding="10" FontSize="36" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Text="اللاعب الثاني" Foreground="#FF919191" GotMouseCapture="redSecond_GotMouseCapture1" FontFamily="Ara Hamah Homs" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="بيانات الفريق الأخضر " FontSize="36" Margin="50,0,50,20" FontFamily="Ara Hamah Homs"  />
    <TextBox x:Name="greenFirst" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,30,0,20" Padding="10" FontSize="36" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Text="اللاعب الأول"  Foreground="#FF919191" GotMouseCapture="greenFirst_GotMouseCapture2" FontFamily="Ara Hamah Homs" />
    <TextBox x:Name="greenSecond" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,30,0,110" Padding="10" FontSize="36" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Text="اللاعب الثاني" Foreground="#FF919191" GotMouseCapture="greenSecond_GotMouseCapture3" FontFamily="Ara Hamah Homs" />

    <Border x:Name="roundsBoarder" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" BorderThickness ="3" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="0" Margin="20,50,20,130" MaxHeight="170" MaxWidth="350" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#99FFFFFF" MouseEnter="Border_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="roundsBoarder_MouseLeave">

     
        
        <StackPanel   HorizontalAlignment="Center"  >
       
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"   >
        <Viewbox Height="40" Width="40" >
            <RadioButton BorderBrush="#FFFFE900"    VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" GroupName="roundsNumber" FontFamily="Ara Hamah Homs" FontSize="12"/>
            </Viewbox>
            <TextBlock Text="جولة" FontSize="42" Margin="20,0,0,0" FontFamily="Alnaqaaa R" />

        </StackPanel>


        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"   >
            <Viewbox Height="40" Width="40" >
                <RadioButton BorderBrush="#FFFFE900"    VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" GroupName="roundsNumber" FontFamily="Ara Hamah Homs" FontSize="12"/>
            </Viewbox>
            <TextBlock Text="ثلاث جولات" FontSize="42" Margin="20,0,0,0" FontFamily="Alnaqaaa R" />

        </StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

First UserControl C#

```
using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows;
 using System.Windows.Controls;
 using System.Windows.Data;
 using System.Windows.Documents;    
 using System.Windows.Input;
 using System.Windows.Media;
 using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
 using System.Windows.Navigation;
 using System.Windows.Shapes; 

 namespace Try3
 {
    public partial class PlayersInfoPage : UserControl
{


    public PlayersInfoPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void redFirst_GotMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        redFirst.Text = "";
        redFirst.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
    }
    private void redSecond_GotMouseCapture1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        redSecond.Text = "";
        redSecond.Foreground = Brushes.Black;

    }


    private void greenFirst_GotMouseCapture2(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        greenFirst.Text = "";
        greenFirst.Foreground = Brushes.Black;

    }

    private void greenSecond_GotMouseCapture3(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        greenSecond.Text = "";
        greenSecond.Foreground = Brushes.Black;

    }

    private void Save_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void Save_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void Border_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        roundsBoarder.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White) { Opacity = 1 };
        roundsBoarder.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(20);
    }

    private void roundsBoarder_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        roundsBoarder.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White) { Opacity = 0.6 };
        roundsBoarder.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(0);

        }
        }
       }
```

Second UserControl xaml to show player names in each side

```
<UserControl x:Class="Try3.gamePage"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:try3"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions >

        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"  >
        
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36" FontFamily="Ara Hamah Homs" Text="الفريق الأحمر" />
    <TextBlock   x:Name="redFirstPlayer" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Ara Hamah Homs" Text="اللاعب الاول" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock   x:Name="redSecondPlayer" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Ara Hamah Homs" Text="اللاعب الثاني" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1">
  
    <TextBlock  FontSize="36" FontFamily="Ara Hamah Homs" Text="الفريق الأخضر" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,20"/>
    <TextBlock  x:Name="greenFirstPlayer" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Ara Hamah Homs" Text="اللاعب الاول" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock  x:Name="greenSecondPlayer" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Ara Hamah Homs" Text="اللاعب الثاني" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    
    </StackPanel>

    <TextBlock x:Name="redScore" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" FontSize="42" FontFamily="Ara Hamah Homs" Text="0" HorizontalAlignment="center" />
    <Image Source="trophy (1).png" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="greenScore" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="3" FontSize="42" FontFamily="Ara Hamah Homs" HorizontalAlignment="center" Text="0" />
    <Image Source="trophy (1).png" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,50,0,0" >



    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: When you create a PlayersInfoPage or a GamePage instance, you can set their DataContext property to a shared view model object, i.e. an instance of a class that exposes public properties that are used as data binding source properties. Unless you do not explicitly set the source object of a Binding, it uses the current DataContext by default. Take a look at [Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0).

Comment: I'm new to WPF that is why I find some of your info confusing but i will definitely check your link , thanks